# Upload multiple Standolane Media Entities (Images) without Reference Field

Tags: media

I'd like to Upload Images as Media Entities without referencing them in another Entity. In `media/add/image` I can upload a single Image. That's fine.
What I'd like to achieve is a Multiple Upload Widget where I can Upload multiple Images and provide default values for all Images (Taxonomy Reference). After creation these Media Entities can be edited further or assigned to other content Entities or just be viewed in Galleries according to their Taxonomy Term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Media Bulk Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_bulk_upload) module will allow you to upload many images at once.

> This is the Drupal 8 module to bulk upload files and create the media
> entities automatically for them. It uses [DropzoneJS](http://www.drupal.org/project/dropzonejs)
> to quickly upload multiple files.

The bulk uploader will allow you to edit fields on the media item before saving. You'll want to set alt text for each image, and your Taxonomy Term reference.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!